# The place to make main functions laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to laravel and I've searched on the internet and on laravel documentation for an answer but there was nothing.

My way of programming is to make a "main" class of functions for Database tables, for example making a class with main functions for users, so I call that class "UsersService" and there are functions like insert update and gets or if I had a payments table so I make a new class that only use this table and call it "PaymentsService" with all the function I need.

I was looking for this kind of thing to do with laravel but haven't found some answers actually...
So guys, where is the best way to make this kind of thing on larvael? in a controller or a model?

Or if you guys had some better way of doing something similar it would be great! :)

Comment: What you are looking for is a model. You can use the generator `php artisan make:model your_model_name`

Comment: @zuif first of all thanks for your answer, I've done it in a model but just wanted to be sure, one more answer how can I make the model to be accessed from any controller, blade, and another model?

Comment: You just import the model in your controller - `use App\YourModelName` to access models in a blade template, just pass the variable (the model stuff) from your controller to the blade `return view('your_view_name', compact('your_variable'));`

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Active Record pattern. Laravel uses [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent).

Then you can use model in your controller like:

```
class BlogController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Posts::all()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Though I prefer Data Mapper pattern used by [Doctrine ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html)

Answer (score 0):

The controller is where I hold all of my main logic and the model is where I put things involved with it. Like for example, I have a program with a incidents controller in which does all of my crud functionality and a Incidents model in which defines my one-to-many relationship with other models as well calls a notification class when a new incident is created. Code is posted below.

Incidents.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\IncidentCreatedNotification;

class Incident extends Model
{

    use Notifiable;

    protected static function boot(){

        parent::boot();

        self::created(function($model){
            $model->notify(new IncidentCreatedNotification());
        });
    }

    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'incidents';

    //Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function status(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
    }
    public function incidentNotes(){
        return $this->hasmany('App\IncidentNotes');
    }

    public function routeNotificationFor($driver){
        //dd(openssl_get_cert_locations());
        //dd(config('app.slack_webhook'));
        return config('app.slack_webhook');
    }

}
```

IncidentsController.php (deleted the logic)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Incident;
use App\IncidentNotes;
use Validator;

class IncidentsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Destroys the Incident 
     *
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {

    }

}
```

What helped me better understand laravel:

Laracasts- https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel

laravel from scratch series- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EU7PRmCpx-0&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-&index=1

Comment: Thanks for that answer! , I've seen you made user and status and more functions at the model that belongs to, can you explain what does it does?, and let's say I had more functions i want to add for example getIncidentName I add it to model?

Comment: So user, status, and incident notes are other models I have connected to that, for example a incident note belongs to specific incident. So they are connected in my database via id's so a incident note has a incident_id column so when I call the incident in my view , I can now pass all of my notes as well and then get all of the notes with the same incident_id as the incident. If you wanted to just get a specific incident name in the view all you would have to do is say something like {{incident->name}} In the view.

Comment: @mordehichro I added a couple links I used when I picked up laravel to help me learn.